# Angular2 Observable.forkJoin of observable variables - ReferenceError: Observable is not defined

Tags: typescript, angular, system.reactive

I'd like to ask you for help. I omitted code that I assume is not important. Let's imagine TS file that contains service calls:

// file: someService.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class SomeService {
     method1(){
         var observable = this.http.get(someUrl)
                          .map((res: Response) =><MyClass[]>res.json());
         return observable;
     }

     method2(){
         // Similar to method1
     }
}
```

// file: someComponent.ts

Please note, that this.method1observable and method2observable are properly assigned from parent (root) component and their type is Observable.

```
import {Observable}     from 'rxjs/Observable';

export class SomeClass {
    public m1: Observable<MyClass[]>;
    public m2: Observable<AnotherClass[]>

    ngOnInit() {
        Observable.forkJoin(this.m1,this.m2) //<- ERROR HERE
        .subscribe(data => {
            this.myFunction(data[0], data[1]);
            requestAnimationFrame(this.renderLoop);
        });
    }
}
```

I get **"Uncaught ReferenceError: Observable is not defined"**.
Don't you know what am I doing wrong? I saw some examples where Observable.forkJoin is called inside a service. But what if I want to call it inside a component?

Comment: Can you try to change `import {Observable}     from 'rxjs/Observable';` to `import 'rxjs/Rx';`?

Comment: Did you `import 'rxjs/add/observable/forkJoin'` or `import 'rxjs/Rx'`?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer : didn't help, still same issue

Comment: @Sasxa affter I added `import 'rxjs/add/observable/forkJoin'`, I get TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined

Comment: How do you include RxJS in your application?

Comment: @ThierryTemplier
`<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.7/Rx.js"></script>`

Then in TS file `import 'rxjs/Rx'`

Comment: There are some issues with adding rxjs operators, import it before importing `Observable`, or better yet import it in your bootstrap file.

Comment: You could try this: import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You could try to import this way:

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';
```

instead of:

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
```

You should also use an array to provide your observables to the forkJoin method:

```
ngOnInit() {
        Observable.forkJoin([this.m1,this.m2])
        .subscribe(data => {
            this.myFunction(data[0], data[1]);
            requestAnimationFrame(this.renderLoop);
        });
    }
```

And do not forget to specify inputs in @Component:

```
@Component({
    inputs: ['m1', 'm2']
})
```

Comment: Yes but it's another error ;-) Are you sure that the observables you provide to forkJoin are not null?

Comment: Is SomeClass a component? Where / how observable properties are set?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure :-) I can do `.subscribe` on each observable and see result. Also google console tells me that they're not null.

Comment: SomeClass is a component. Observables are set in parent component:
`ngOnInit(){}`

Comment: `ngOnInit(){
    this.m1 = this._someService.method1();
    this.m2 = this._someService.method2();
}`

and view definition:

`@Component({
      template:'<myDirective [m1]=m1 [m2]=m2></myDirective>'
})
`

Comment: Okay make sense! What do you have at line 8533 in the Rx.js file?

Comment: source.subscribe(new AllSubscriber(subscriber, i, context));

1st call:

source is Observable, subscriber is Subscriber, context is Object, i = 0

2nd call:

source is undefined, subscriber is Subscriber, context is Object, i = 1

Comment: Could you try: Observable.forkJoin([ obs1, obs2 ]);

Comment: I think I've already tried this option. Exception remains. BUT, I put breakpoint inside a subscribe(data => ... here ... ) function and I can see, that data variable is filled in properly - data[0] and data[1] contains correct data.

Comment: Heh... I think I got it. The second exception belongs to code below (typo mistake). But MAIN reason was that I forgot to specify 2nd Observable (m2) in *@Component { inputs : ['m1', **'m2'**] }*

Answer (score 5):

You should avoid importing the whole rxjs library as it is quite big. If you have the following imports **anywhere** in your app, you will be importing the whole rxjs, so have that in mind:

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
```

or

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';
```

You can instead import the **individual features** that you will be using, for example:

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/forkJoin';
```

**UPDATE:** Starting with rxjs 5.5, [the recommended way to import operators is](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/lettable-operators.md):

```
import { range } from 'rxjs/observable/range';
import { map, filter, scan } from 'rxjs/operators';

const source$ = range(0, 10);

source$.pipe(
  filter(x => x % 2 === 0),
  map(x => x + x),
  scan((acc, x) => acc + x, 0)
)
.subscribe(x => console.log(x))
```

Comment: I have set it up like what you have in three lines but still getting error "forkJoin does not exist on type of Observable" I am using webpack

Comment: It's just typescript throws error "forkJoin does not exist on type of Observable" like this in the visual studio.

Comment: Sorry don't know how to further help you, for me importing forkJoin is all its needed for that error to go away.

Answer (score 3):

you can refer to this link for more information about using forkjoin() method to run multiple concurrent http.get() requests.Here u can get a complete working example.

http://www.metaltoad.com/blog/angular-2-http-observables

Comment: You'd get more points if you put an example using it, and not only the link, it's a good link, thank you :)