# How to know when all Angular2 HTTP calls are finished

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm writing an application that will monitor the current build number of all of our applications across different servers.  This is done by making an http request to a txt file in every application.  I'm doing that using a foreach loop.

The issue I'm having is that I'm not sure how (using Observables) to know when all of the requests are finished.

As the requests come back, I add the response as a property of an array of objects.  Then once I have all of the data, I bind it to the component's template, where it gets filtered by a Pipe.  As such, I need to make sure I don't bind it until all of the data is finished coming down.

Here is how I'm getting the data:

```
this.apps.forEach(app => {
  app.Environments.forEach(env => {
    this._buildMonitorService.getBuilds(env.URL)
      .subscribe((data) => {     
        setupBuilds(this.apps,data.url,data._body);
      });                
  });
});
```

`setupBuilds` adds the response to my array of applications.

The thing I'm looking for is effectively a `Promise.all` where I'll bind 
`this.builds` to the data setup in `setupBuilds` but I don't know how to do that with rxjs observables

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`Observable.forkJoin` is the equivalent to `Promise.all` but for observables.

Here is a sample:

- [Angular2 Observable.forkJoin of observable variables - ReferenceError: Observable is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35699898/angular2-observable-forkjoin-of-observable-variables-referenceerror-observabl/35700233#35700233)

Here is the way you could refactor your code:

```
var observables = [];
this.apps.forEach(app => {
  app.Environments.forEach(env => {
    observables.push(this._buildMonitorService.getBuilds(env.URL));
  });
});

Observable.forkJoin(observables).subscribe(
  (result) => {
    result.forEach((data) => {
      setupBuilds(this.apps,data.url,data._body);
    });
  }
);
```

This way you will be sure that all requests were executed when the callback registered in the subscribe method is called...

Comment: So, I tried setting this up (first my own way and then again with your edited code), and I'm getting `Observable_1.Observable.forkJoin is not a function`

Comment: I do think your answer will be what I'm looking for, but it's not quite working

Comment: You need to import the operator: `import 'rxjs/add/operator/forkJoin';` or import everything from rxjs `import 'rxjs/Rx';`

Comment: I already am with `import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';`

Comment: Yes but it only import a minimal set of methods on the `Observable` class. Try this: `import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';` to have all (or import the operators one by one)...

Comment: @ThierryTemplier for me was `import 'import 'rxjs/add/observable/forkJoin';` ..add/observable instead ...add/operator

Comment: @ThierryTemplier   Hi , how can i check each response before push them into an observable ?  because i need to know if  response.toJson().Done is equal to true or not . If not , so we can push it into the observables[] .

Comment: What if I have different types of HTTP requests and they all need to be handled in a different way i.e., I want to keep their code in the individual subscribe methods but I still want to know when all the HTTP request observables have completed. I don't care about getting the last emitted values from each observable in the forkJoin subscribe array. I only want to know when all the observables have completed