# Angular 2 : merge several http calls into one

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I have a service that is used to upload pictures. To upload a picture, all I do is

```
return this.http.post(/* ... */)
```

And I get a subscription I can subscribe to in my component. But when I want to upload several pictures, I have to do

```
for (let p of pics) { this.http.post(/* ... */); }
```

My problem is that I would like to return the results of **all calls** instead of just one call. Is that possible ?

**EDIT** Here is my service

```
addPictures(files: File[], folder: string): Observable<Parse.Object[]> {
  let hasError = false;
  for (let file of files) {
    let [type, ext] = file.type.split('/');
    if (type.toLowerCase() !== 'image' || !environment.imgExts.includes(ext.toLowerCase())) { hasError = true; }
  }
  if (hasError) { return Observable.throw('Invalid extension detected'); }

  let observables: Observable<Parse.Object>[] = [];

  for (let file of files) {
    // Get its size
    let img = new Image();
    img.onload = () => {
      // Create the Parse document
      let parseImg = { url: '', type: file.type, width: img.width, height: img.height };
      // Upload it on Amazon and add it to DB
      observables.push(this.addPicture(parseImg, file, folder));
    }
    img.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(file);
  }
  return Observable.forkJoin(observables);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to know when all Angular2 HTTP calls are finished](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36014508/how-to-know-when-all-angular2-http-calls-are-finished)

Comment: fyi, I didn't downvote the question

Comment: I'm looking at this answer right now, thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to run all the requests in parallel you can use `forkJoin()`:

```
const observables = pics.map(p => this.http.post(/* ... */));

Observable.forkJoin(observables)
  .subscribe(results => ...);
```

You could eventually use `Observable.merge()` to receive results as they arrive or eventually `Observable.concat()` to call requests one after another.

Comment: It's perfectly correct, but isn't it a dupe as you'd appreciate? You can provide the answer under the dupe question as meta forum suggests :/

Comment: Well I don't know, I'm testing the solutoin given in the duplicate comment (but it looks a lot like yours). Why would I use `Observable.merge` ? I'm asking how to merge already. Forkjoin doesn't merge automatically ?

Comment: @trichetriche Because `forkJoin()` emits only after all the Observables completed. However `merge` emits every item from every Observable immediately.

Comment: Oh I see, that means in my subscribe I will have a table of subscriptions, while with `merge` it will only be one ?

Comment: An array of subscription to be precise, but yes.

Comment: I have an issue, I edited my post with my service, would you be able to help ? I tried putting logs under `observables.push` and they fired, but the method `addPicture` isn't triggered (this function works, I use it for a single image). Am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: @trichetriche `addPicture` method will only be fired after you subscribe to `addPictures` method

Comment: Sorry, I subscribed to it, what I meant is that `addPictures` is called, but `addPicture` isn't. my subscription is here `this.pictureService.addPictures(ng2Files, 'ForkJoin').subscribe(data => console.log(data));`

Comment: In fact the problem comes from me. `addPicture` is called, but the http calls in it aren't. I'll correct that and see what happens. Anyway, the number of calls matches the number of calls I did, so your solution works. Thank you !

Comment: @martin if you edit your answer, I'll retract the downvote.