# how to merge requests into one observable angular 2

Tags: angular, observable, angular2-rc5

There are several requests in subscribe and the same number is obtained at the output due to which the traffic leak.
I tried flatMap, map.
Maybe who come across and know how to solve?

```
Observable.fromEvent(document.querySelector('employees'), 'input')
      .debounceTime(500)
      .distinctUntilChanged()
      .subscribe((event) => {
          this.searchFilter(Value);
      });
```

Comment: have you tried `forkJoin`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 : merge several http calls into one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45301745/angular-2-merge-several-http-calls-into-one)