# property 'forkJoin' does not exist on type 'typeof observable' - angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I was looking to experiment with a forkJoin mainly using the accepted answer here:

[Angular2 Observable.forkJoin of observable variables - ReferenceError: Observable is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35699898/angular2-observable-forkjoin-of-observable-variables-referenceerror-observabl)

I'm getting the above error message as forkJoin isn't available.

Anyone know why?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Angular 6 changes this up a bit.  forkJoin has been converted to a regular function so, instead of:

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
...
return Observable.forkJoin(
    this.http.get('someurl'),
    this.http.get('someotherurl'));
```

Use:

```
import {forkJoin} from 'rxjs';
...
return forkJoin(
    this.http.get('someurl'),
    this.http.get('someotherurl'));
```

You can go to https://www.metaltoad.com/blog/angular-6-upgrading-api-calls-rxjs-6 for more explanation.

Answer (score 49):

Did you do this?

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/forkJoin';
```

You have to add methods individually.

Comment: Note that this is a static method, so as Dan wrote, you have to `import 'rxjs/add/observable/forkJoin'`, and _not_ `import 'rxjs/add/operator/forkJoin'`. Have been bitten by that twice...

Answer (score 13):

You just need to replace

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
```

by

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
```

and it will start working

Warning: Do not use this method as it will include the entire RxJs library (increasing kb bundle size)

Comment: @dan-cancro 's solution is better if you do not want to download the entire library.

Comment: Really, really don't import all of `"rxjs/Rx"`, it's *huge* and most projects won't use more than a very small number of its exports.

Comment: this solution worked fine with Angular 4 for me, but I'm having issues with Angular 5 (in production build)

Comment: Warning: Do not use this method as it will include the entire RxJs library (increasing kb bundle size)

Answer (score 3):

Check your version of Rxjs, if you are using Rxjs 6, use

`import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/forkJoin';`

won't work, use  `import { Observable, forkJoin } from 'rxjs'` instead

Answer (score 1):

I have been running Angular version 5.2.0 and faced similar problem. So instead of calling observable with the following way

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/observable'
```

I imported *Observable* by including the entire RxJs library

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx'
```

Then for the *forkJoin*, included the below import module

```
import 'rxjs/add/observable/forkJoin';
```

and code compiled successfully.

Answer (score 1):

For me, Angular 4 it helps:

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';
instead of:
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
```